# How to trigger data-click event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Html i have a sidebar with an anchor on which i can click to expand/collapse the sidebar, however i would like to achieve with javascript. Here is what i have tried but i am not getting the desired results.

***Html file:***

```
<!-- begin sidebar minify button -->
<a href="javascript:;" class="sidebar-minify-btn" data-click="sidebar-minify">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
</a>
<!-- end sidebar minify button -->
```

***js file :***

```
  window.onresize = function()
  {
     const width = window.innerWidth;
     if(width <= 800)
     {
       $('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').click(function(event)
       {
          console.log('sidebar clicked');
       }
     }
  }
```

Basically what i want to achieve is to detect if the browser window width has changed to less than 800px and then trigger the click event on the sidebar. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, [jQuery click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) is used to attach an event handler to the element. Looks like you are doing this correctly.

What you're looking for is [jQuery trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/), with which you can trigger an event. In your case, try

```
$('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but maybe another question that the event is triggered forever .How to stop the event once it is triggered once ?

Comment: Follow-on question has been correctly added as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804192/trigger-click-event-only-once