# Trigger click event only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the click event only when the screen width of the browser is 800px, however with the logic below, the click event is triggered back and forth nonstop when i reach at the 800 and stop resizing the screen. How can i fix this issue.

**html file:**

```
<!-- begin sidebar minify button -->
<a href="javascript:;" class="sidebar-minify-btn" data-click="sidebar-minify">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
</a>
<!-- end sidebar minify button -->
```

**js file:**

```
window.onresize = function()
{
     const width = window.innerWidth;
     if(width === 800)
     {

        $('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').trigger('click');
        console.log('click event triggered');
     }
}
```

Comment: set a global bool to false and once you trigger the click set it to true and only do the click if it is false; or bind the click using `.one` - https://api.jquery.com/one/; or unbind the resize event in your click event

Comment: What does the click on the anchor do? If it redirects to the same page, `window.resize` is triggered on the page load, and that might make the anchor being clicked again. However, it's very unlikely the width of the window being exactly 800 px when resize fires.

Comment: How? Would you elaboration a bit ? Appreciate

Comment: the click on the anchor expand or collapse the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way could be to remove the `resize` listener when no longer needed using [EventTarget.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) like this:

```
function resizeListener() {
  if (window.innerWidth === 800) {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
    $('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').trigger('click');
    console.log('click event triggered');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
```

Comment: Given that the only logic that the resize does is related to triggering the click, this makes the most sense.

Comment: @Xris, thanks for fixing the typo. I rejected the rest of your edit because it added new logic to renew the resizeListener after a manual click which  was not part of your original question. I just wanted to keep the code example simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onresize = function()
{
 const width = window.innerWidth;
 if(width === 800)
 {
   // give anker link class then remove that after condition true


    $('.anker').trigger('click');


    console.log('click event triggered');

   $('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').removeClass("anker");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Pete said in the comments, you have different options.

You could use a boolean to track if the event already was fired:

```
var isResized = false;
window.onresize = function()
{
     const width = window.innerWidth;
     if(width === 800 && !isResized)
     {
        isResized = true;
        alert("test");
     }
}
```

You also can use the `one` function for the click of the `a tag`, which unbinds the click after the first use:

```
window.onresize = function()
{
     const width = window.innerWidth;
     if(width === 800)
     {
        $('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').trigger('click');
        console.log('click event triggered');
     }
}

$('a[data-click="sidebar-minify"]').one("click", function(){
    alert("test");
});
```